# atmospheric correction in ENVI 5.1

Tags: remote-sensing, envi

I want to perform atmospheric correction on Landsat 8 images in ENVI 5.1. In order to create radiance image, I selected basic tools> preprocessing> calibration utilities> Landsat calibration. However, OLI sensor does not exist in sensor type. Would you please help me how I can perform this analysis in ENVI 5?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Exelis video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6IqEysywtw). Use the new interface - not the classic view.